# How to format a comma separated decimal value in Rich Text Format?

Tags: rtf

I have given below code in the format section of .rtf file to generate report

```
      0.00 is the desired output
      .00 is the output coming now


   Number,
   ###,###,###,###,##0.00
```

Answer (score 1):

Standard numeric format strings are used to format common numeric types. A standard numeric format string takes the form Axx, where:

"C" or "c"  Currency
"D" or "d"  Decimal 
"E" or "e"  Exponential (scientific)
"F" or "f"  Fixed-point 
"G" or "g"  General 
"N" or "n"  Number
"P" or "p"  Percent 
"R" or "r"  Round-trip
"X" or "x"  Hexadecimal

When you append a number after that It'll generally mean precision. N2 means comma-separated number with double precision.

```
var amount = 1234567890.62;
var formattedString = $"{amount,0:N2}";
Console.WriteLine(formattedString);
```

I saw the below output

```
1,234,567,890.62
Press any key to continue . . .
```

more here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-numeric-format-strings